# WordPress wp_insert_term: tag description with HTML format

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin to WP , i made a tag generator using wp_insert_term but it ignores user's html format in description field. for example: `{<h1> Example </h1>}` shows only "Example"(without Heading) in description of new tag. Text for description is added by html textarea field which is on my plugin site. Any ideas how to add tags description with HTML form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default WordPress strips HTML from category descriptions. You can get around this by adding a small snippet to your theme functions.php file:

```
//prevents html from being stripped from term descriptions 
foreach ( array( 'pre_term_description' ) as $filter ) {
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_filter_kses' );
}

//prevents html being stripped out when using the term description function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description).
foreach ( array( 'term_description' ) as $filter ) {
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_kses_data' );
}
```